# Как правильно сделать формат даты?

Tags: php

Нужно вывести `вчера` `сегодня` `завтра` именно в таком формате

> 06.05.2021
> 07.05.2021
> 08.05.2021

```
$d = date( "d" );
$m = date( "m" );
$Y = date( "Y" );
$d1 = date( "d" )+1;
$d2 = date( "d" )-1;

<div class="sh">0$d2.$m.$Y</div>
<div class="sh">$d.$m.$Y</div>
<div class="sh">0$d1.$m.$Y</div>
```

Чую, что этот код далеко не идеальный. С нолём перед датой дня проблемы.

Comment: `$tomorrow = date('d m Y', strtotime(strtotime(date('now')).' +1 day')); $yesterday = date('d m Y', strtotime(strtotime(date('now')).' -1 day'));` Просто работать со временем надо, а не добавлять нули

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас всё чаще используют класс `DateTime / DateTimeImmutable`:

```php
$datetime = new DateTimeImmutable();

$format = 'd.m.Y';

echo
  $datetime->modify('-1 day')->format($format) . "\n" .
  $datetime->format($format) . "\n" .
  $datetime->modify('+1 day')->format($format) . "\n";
```

- https://replit.com/@w3lifer/DiscreteOutlyingText#main.php
- https://php.net/class.datetimeimmutable

Comment: Почему у меня `Fatal error: Class 'DateTimeImmutable' not found`

Comment: У меня php 5.4.45

Comment: @steep, https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuBgX.png

Comment: Значит надо что-то другое

Comment: Для добавления нолей можете использовать такую функцию: https://github.com/w3lifer/php-helper/blob/master/PhpHelper.php#L71

Comment: как это использовать?

Comment: @steep, как обычную функцию.